# How to rename individual pages in a PDF? (PDF labels) -- Ubuntu

Tags: pdf

I have been attempting to find software or an online service that I can use to rename individual pages inside a PDF with.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

I have spent over 14 hours trying out different software and *none* seem to be able to accomplish this simple task.

Answer (score 1):

`LibreDraw` have that feature.

- Open the pdf using `LibreDraw`
- Select the page in page plane, then click on `Page` menu, and select `Rename page`
- After editing, select `export as > export as pdf` from the file menu.

Comment: This is a great answer! A screenshot walkthrough would be useful here as you are recommending GUI actions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Adobe Acrobat: https://answers.acrobatusers.com/how-rename-page-PDF-q91181.aspx

"Open the Pages panel on the left. Right-click the page and select Number Pages. Under "Pages" select "Selected". Under "Numbering" select Style: None, Prefix: Cover, Start: 1, and click OK."

Comment: This isn't a feasible option for me. I cannot use Adobe products (I can use just about anything else however).